# Can prosecutors and/or judges be sued for dereliction of duty when they change charges to avoid a jury trial?

Tags: traffic, jury, trial, utah, civil-rights

Scenario (Utah, USA): A defendant is arraigned at a pre-trial hearing. Charges include driving without insurance and driving with an expired license.
State law declares that those who do these things are guilty of misdemeanors in each case, and prescribes a minimum penalty for each if found guilty.

The defendant expresses a desire for a trial, and seeing that these are criminal charges, he exercises his State and Federal Constitutional right to a jury trial to respond to those charges.

The judge immediately prevaricates and solicits input from the prosecutor, who promptly adjusts the charges to "infractions". The judge then repeatedly affirms that a jury trial is not an option because no criminal charges are being made, despite criminal charges having been the cause of the arraignment.

The judge attempts to coerce either a bench trial or a plea deal, repeatedly saying that since no criminal charges are being made, no jury trial can be arranged.

The State Constitution also says that "All laws of a general nature shall have uniform operation".

In the same jurisdiction, people arraigned with identical initial charges and with comparable evidences against them have been charged as misdemeanors, pled guilty or issued a plea in abeyance, and were convicted by a bench trial with no further findings beyond police reports or pulling their traffic records, and were left with a criminal record on account of the conviction, and required to pay a commensurate fine and being required to conform to additional sentencing.

Can the prosecutor and/or the judge be sued for dereliction of duty, and for non-uniform application of the law?
Can the outcome of a bench trial be appealed on grounds that the judge did not inform the defendant of his rights or that his rights were taken away by unwarranted modification of the charges?

Comment: What's the actus reus for the infractions that the misdemeanor charges got adjusted to? If it is the same as for the misdemeanors, then how do the latter differ? Some mens rea added on top of the actus reus?

Comment: They are identical. No mens rea could be alleged for the misdemeanor status, except by the "not guilty" plea entered by requesting a trial. Mens rea would make no difference the way the law is worded; the minimum punishments including misdemeanor status are uniform irrespective of intent (although there is enhancement language for repeat offenders). I have found no laws on the books fitting the description of the allegations that should be charged as infractions; the reduction to infraction status is an arbitrary maneuver by the prosecutor in disregard of the minimum statutory definitions.

Comment: I removed the insurance tag as it didn't seem to have any connection with the real question here, and added a Utah tag.

Answer (score 3):

> Can the prosecutor and/or the judge be sued for dereliction of duty,
> and for non-uniform application of the law?

No.

Judges and prosecutors have absolute immunity from civil liability for their actions in the course of their duties in connection with the court process.

Prosecutors have effectively absolute discretion in their charging decisions and in their decisions to reduce the charges sought against a defendant (prior to jeopardy attaching when a jury is sworn in).

> Can the outcome of a bench trial be appealed on grounds that the judge
> did not inform the defendant of his rights

Yes.

> or that his rights were taken away by unwarranted modification of the
> charges?

No.

Incidentally, there is no federal constitutional right to a jury trial in a case where six months or less of incarceration is sought as a penalty, and there is no federal constitutional right to counsel unless incarceration is a possible penalty.

The Utah State Constitution distinguishes between criminal matters and non-criminal matters in several respects mostly found in the state's bill of Rights ([Article I of the State Constitution](https://le.utah.gov/xcode/UC_1800010118000101.pdf)) in Sections 8, 10, 12, 13, and 19.

But, it is fundamentally the right of the state through its prosecutors to decide what charges to press against someone, and they are well within their rights to change their minds. Often, this will be in your favor because reducing an offense to a civil infraction rather than a misdemeanor will have far fewer collateral consequences related to having a criminal record.

Comment: Can you cite the Federal or State law(s) made pursuant to their respective Constitutions that guarantee civil immunity for prosecutors and judges? Or is it only a rule of nonlegal procedure or precedent?

How do you reconcile prosecutorial discretion for charging irrespective of what the evidences support with a Constitutional stipulation that the application of all laws shall be uniform?

Can judges or prosecutors face criminal liability over unfair or nonuniform application of the laws, or denying defendants their rights? Dereliction of duty would be a criminal suit, not a civil one.

Comment: @pygosceles "Can judges or prosecutors face criminal liability over unfair or nonuniform application of the laws, or denying defendants their rights?" Usually not, certainly the OP question would not be such a case. Civil immunity generally is largely a function of case law. For absolute prosecutorial immunity see *Imbler v. Pachtman*, 424 U.S. 409 (1976). For judicial immunity see e.g., *State ex rel. Jacobs v. Sherard*, 36 N.C. App 60, 64 (1978). The requirement that laws be uniform goes to the laws and not to their enforcement. See, e.g. *Castle Rock v. Gonzales*, 545 U.S. 748 (2005).

Comment: @pygosceles The ban on non-uniform legislation is aimed at situations common, e.g., in the State of New York, where the laws on a great manner issues (e.g. court organization and eviction and foreclosure rules) are different in Buffalo than they are in Albany than they are in New York City.

Comment: Why would the OP question exempt the possibility of criminal liability? Denying the right to a jury trial is a very serious criminal liability, regardless of the severity of any case or charge in which a civil servant waived that right. We sometimes treat rights seriously when it comes to law enforcement officers, but what about higher positions in the criminal justice system? Where are the civil rights champions today?
If the only basis for such an exemption is a corpus of verdicts or case opinions, those have no binding authority since that would be legislating from the bench.

Comment: Citing the Constitution of the state in the OP:

"Article I, Section 24 [Uniform operation of laws.]
All laws of a general nature shall have uniform operation."

This is clearly an injunction on the operation or application of the laws, not exclusively on the nature of the laws themselves; therefore it has applicability to prosecutorial and judicial roles.

Comment: @pygosceles You can believe me or not. But I am telling you what these provision mean in practice as they have been interpreted by  the courts over time in the bigger picture. I can see how you might think that this means what you think it does, but it doesn't.

Comment: "Why would the OP question exempt the possibility of criminal liability?" Because nobody has done anything wrong. Prosecutors are perfectly entitled to bring a lesser charge that in turn affords you fewer rights. That's a tactical choice that prosecutors get to make. The system gives them a choice between more serious charges with more rights and more lenient charges with fewer rights. In the U.S. as a common law country, legislating from the bench is allowed and fundamental to how the system works.

Comment: Naturally the courts would interpret it to mean that they can bear no liability therefrom, which is another excellent reason why we need to exercise the right to jury trial with regularity.
Laws are by definition not uniform in their operation if the enforcers and adjudicators of it are arbitrary.

Comment: Denying a civil right is a crime and a dereliction of duty for any officer of public trust, by definition.

Prosecutors who deviate from the prescribed statutory definitions and requirements are violating the law by doing so, and are liable.

The Constitution does not tolerate either the forfeiture of defendant rights due to improper charging or inappropriate procedure. The courts cannot deny rights by calling a charge an "infraction" rather than a misdemeanor.
Legislating from the bench is prohibited in the US. Common law is defined by the common people, not by careerists.

Comment: @pygosceles Justice via jury verdict is about as far from uniform in operation as you can get.

Comment: "Denying a civil right is a crime and a dereliction of duty for any officer of public trust, by definition." Got any authority for that? And, nobody has denied anyone's civil rights here. You don't have a right to trial by jury in anything that could have been charged as a crime. There is no right to a jury trial by calling a charge an infraction and it changes the consequences and what your rights are. Your understanding of the legal system is deeply incorrect.

Comment: It is evident that you disagree fundamentally with the organization and function of Constitutional republics, which have their basis in limited government, checks and balances, the consent of the governed, and are subject to such safeguards against arbitrariness as Conscience and common sense. Jury trial is an inalienable right, and your opposition to it explains the contortions.
There can be no meaningful and enduring checks or balances among mortals in a system that disconnects itself from the judicial sense of common people.

Comment: @pygosceles Sorry, but that's just wrong. The law in the US generally does *not* require prosecutors to bring every charge they can. Civil rights are not violated if a prosecutor drops charges to avoid violating a right. Legislating from the bench is a fundamental principle of the US legal system. Common law is created by judges through decisions, not by the common people.

Comment: How's the supreme law of the land?

"The trial of all crimes... shall be by jury" -Article III, Section 2, Clause 3 of the United States Constitution.

The authorized legal system is what the Founding Fathers gave us, not what corrupt politburo arrogated to itself.

Calling a criminal charge an infraction does not change this one bit. It does not change the law, and it does not change the defendant's rights. It is expressly a maneuver designed to rob the citizenry of their rights.

Comment: "Drops charges to avoid violating a right"
Do you have any examples of this?

Precedent derived from career officials is no more valid than the strength of the arguments they provide.

Comment: @pygosceles The trial of federal crimes is by jury, but the U.S. Constitution doesn't directly regulate state criminal procedure in the same way. Article III of the U.S. Constitution concerns the organization of the federal courts.

Comment: @pygosceles "Precedent derived from career officials is no more valid than the strength of the arguments they provide." In a civil law country, you'd be right. But Utah and the United States are common law countries where that isn't how it works.

Comment: @pygosceles The legal system the Founding Fathers left to us was a common-law system. A *defining principle* of those systems is that judicial opinions are binding law in their own right, not just because they're persuasive but because they were made by a judicial officer resolving a case.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141771/discussion-on-answer-by-ohwilleke-can-prosecutors-and-or-judges-be-sued-for-dere).